# How do I disable default focused effect on UIButton in tvOS 15

Tags: tvos

Before the tvOS 15, I can set UIButton type to `Custom` to disable default focused effect. But it is no working now. Anyone know how to do that ?

Answer (score 0):

You can see the right side panel and check the "Style", it has to be set to "Default".
My version of Xcode is 13.2.1, the button default style would be set to "Plain".

Panel

[image: 1]